# I can't increase the max upload file size for wordpress on local install?

Tags: uploads

I am running a local dev installation of Wordpress. I try to upload a 32MB video but I can't increase the upload file size past 8M.

My php.ini is set to 200M

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

I have restarted php fpm and even apache2.
Then I tried to add

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '256M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '256M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

to functions.php

Still the max upload size remains unchanged 8M.

Answer (score 0):

The `@ini_set()` option is `upload_max_filesize`, not `upload_max_size`. See [the full list on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard text editor to open /etc/php/apache2/php.ini, search for the following variables and change/increase these to:

memory_limit = 512M

upload_max_filesize = 512M

post_max_size = 512M

save the changes and restart apache

sudo service apache2 restart

or

sudo systemctl restart apache2